# Crystal Reports and Internet Explorer (6 and others)

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, crystal-reports

I need to define and design a future web application, implemented in ASP.NET, that will use reports (tables and different kind of graphics) and MUST:

- Work in all web browsers (including Internet Explorer 6)
- Work without any extra component, like Active X control or plugin or whatever

I'm thinking in Crystal Reports, and so far I have googled *"crystal reports internet explorer"* and have seen a number of entries regarding *Active X control* or *I can't see crytal reports in internet explorer, need Active X*, etc.

My questions are:

Is there anybody who has experience in Crystal Reports for ASP.NET? Does it work in Internet Explorer without any extra component? What about Internet Explorer 6?

Thank you

Comment: A new web application that needs to work in IE6 in 2011? Awwwww. http://ie6countdown.com/

Comment: If anyone asks you to support IE6, tell them it will double the cost of the project.

Comment: Yes, don't tell me, I just have to acomplish user needs, and yes, i will rise the cost of the project (and lower the quality), but by now I need to find out this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you want graphs without any plugins, the best suggestion I can make is to look into the [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) Javascript graphics library, and [g.Raphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/), its companion library dedicated to producing graphs and charts.

It works in all browsers, including IE6, and produces vector graphics, so they scale perfectly, and there's no jagged edges.

As for tables.... well, HTML can cope with those.  :-)